# Logical Error in loop when trying to save database records

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read all the records of a database using .net, and I have a logical error in the while loop, I can't understand what the problem is, if someone could take a look I would greatly appreciate.

```
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection  con;
    DataSet dsl;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da;
    public String accessDatabase()
    {
        initializecomponent();

        con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\CIS3052.mdb";
        dsl = new DataSet();
        String displayID = null;
         String displayFname = null;
         String displayLname = null;
         String displayAge = null;
         String displayJob = null;
         String viewAll = null;
         int inc = 0;
         int MaxRows = 0;


        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
        da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dsl, "Employee");

        MaxRows = dsl.Tables["Employee"].Rows.Count;
        while (inc != MaxRows -1)
        {

        DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["Employee"].Rows[inc];
        displayID = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
        displayFname = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        displayLname = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        displayAge = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
        displayJob = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
        viewAll = viewAll + displayID + " " + displayFname + " " + displayLname + " " + displayAge + " " + displayJob + " ";
        }



        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();



        return viewAll;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Try to be a little more specific: what are you expecting and what are you getting instead?

Comment: For a start you're not incrementing `inc`, so you're only looking at the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try with a For-Loop ??

```
for(int i = 0; i < MaxRows; i++)
{    
    DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["Employee"].Rows[i];
    displayID = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
    displayFname = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
    displayLname = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
    displayAge = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
    displayJob = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
    viewAll = viewAll + displayID + " " + displayFname + " " + displayLname + " " + displayAge + " " + displayJob + " ";
}
```

Comment: I tried this and made some progress but I'm just getting the first record displayed for the number of  times there are records

Comment: Great it works just have to change:

DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["Employee"].Rows[inc];

to
DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["Employee"].Rows[i];

Thanks alot =)

Answer (score 0):

Replace
        while (inc != MaxRows -1)
        {

with
        for (int inc=0; inc < MaxRows; inc++)
        {